# Cleaning up DataFrame due to text wrapping creating multiple lines

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, word-wrap

I have a DataFrame I'm working with that split based on text wrapping.  The description has been split over multiple rows, where the key data, in a separate column "Values" only appears in the first line of the description.  I'm hoping to do two things:

1. Merge the information in the description from the additional wrapped rows.
2. Remove the additional rows with no "Values"

[image]

I've been trying iterating through the rows, but with little success.  Here is some sample code showing the problem dataframe (just an example):

```
import pandas as pd
a = ["This is", "the first", "line", "second", "line", "third", "line", "(no pattern)", "fourth", "fifth"]
b = [1, "", "", 3, "", 47, "", "", 1, 2]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Description'] = a
df['Values'] = b
df.head(10)
```

I've tried a few things.  Right now I'm just trying to get the loop to identify if "Values" has anything in it, here is the current, short, code i'm working with:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
if row.Values != '':
    a = row["Description"]
else:
    b = row["Description"]
    c = a + b
    print(c)
    #print(row["Values"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the links, very useful information.  I'll keep trying to refine my question, is there anything specific you can recommend to improve the question?

Comment: Please show us the code that you're having problems with. What you have so far is just an example DF.

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo!  I've been trying multiple code to get it started.  Right now i'm just working with identifying with values and then without values.  My next step is to concat "Description" before next 'Value' is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after working on this all day I got an answer!!!  It does seem long-winded, if you have an alternate answer, please let me know.  Here is my answer:

```
a_array = np.array([]) 
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.Values != '':
        a = int(index)
    a_array = np.append(a_array, a)
df['a']= a_array
df['Description'] = df.groupby(['a'])['Description'].transform(lambda x: ' '.join(x))
df.replace("", np.nan, inplace=True) # replace blank values with NaN
df.dropna(subset = ['Values']) #Drop rows with NaN in Values
```

This code works by iterating through the rows, and identifying the index when a value appears in "Values".  I add that as a dataframe column, 'a', and then group by the value of 'a' joining all the strings with a space ' '.

Then the blanks have the NaN value entered (np.nan), and I drop all rows with a NaN in the column "Values".

Answer (score 1):

This avoids plain Python iteration, which is slow in Pandas. The key here is to find a pairing of the numbers in the Values column and the entries in Description; this pairing will allow us to get the rows beneath where Values are empty and safely stick them back to the line(s) above :

```
res = (df
       #create a new column
       #to hold rows where Values is not empty
       .assign(desc = np.where(df.Values.ne(""),df.Description,np.nan))
       #change the empty rows to null
       .replace({"":np.nan})
       #fill downwards
       .ffill()
       #ensure sort is False
       #to keep data as is
       .groupby(['Values','desc'],sort=False)
       #join similar rows with white space
       .agg(" ".join)
       #drop the desc index
       #it has served its purpose
       .droplevel('desc')
       .reset_index()
      )

res

  Values    Description
0   1.0     This is the first line
1   3.0     second line
2   47.0    third line (no pattern)
3   1.0     fourth
4   2.0     fifth
```

Answer (score 1):

First, build a unique index we can use to group the descriptions by. Since the Values column is an indicator of the start of a new valid group, we can group by blocks of non-empty Values followed by empty rows. We'll differentiate them using a cumulative sum, incrementing each non-empty Value:

```py
In [2]: grouper = (df.Values != '').cumsum()
In [3]: grouper
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
6    3
7    3
8    4
9    5
Name: Values, dtype: int64
```

We can use this in a pandas groupby operation, where the operation returns the joined descriptions and the non-empty Value in each group:

```py
In [4]: df.groupby(grouper).apply(
   ...:     lambda x: pd.Series({
   ...:         'Description': ' '.join(x.Description),
   ...:         'Values': x.Values.values[x.Values != 0][0]
   ...:     })
   ...: ).reset_index(drop=True)

               Description  Values
0   This is the first line       1
1              second line       3
2  third line (no pattern)      47
3                   fourth       1
4                    fifth       2
```